# Database Design: List All Combinations or Use Matrix

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

My colleague and I are learning more about database design. We found a situation where we don't know what the next step is. I like to think of it of having 3 combo boxes. I choose the first 2 values and the last one is filtered accordingly to the first 2. Imagine we have 3 tables: `Color Table, Material Table, Size Table`.

Below is Color Table Design:

```
ID   | Color_Name   | Material_ID | Size_ID
```

In order to choose a Color, it depends on filtering by `Material_ID` and `Size_ID`. We have over 600 Colors to choose from. We have 6 different Materials. Lets say Color Red can be used by 4 Materials. So in the Color Table you would have at least 4 records for Red. So this table could technically have a max of `600 * 6 *` (# of sizes).

The problem with this is that we would have to enter in all those records. The Color Table would be a **static** table(very rare we would enter in more colors).    Would it be best practice to enter in every combination possible in this table?

Or do we use a matrix to find out every possible combination? I would assume the matrix would be a table, but not sure how you would create a matrix table that compares more than 2 fields(would have to create multidimensional tables).

We would like to follow best practice for designing the database which would help with maintenance. We are open to all suggestions/ideas on how this is handled in the real world. **Thank you for your time!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Color table is poorly designed and in need of normalization. Every color should be recorded only once:

```
Color (ID PK, Color_Name)
```

And then the combinations of materials, sizes and colors can be represented as a ternary relation:

```
ColorMaterialSize (Color_ID, Material_ID, Size_ID)
```

Take some time to think about this one. Is any combination of one or two columns unique/identifying, or are all combinations of the three columns valid? Define your primary key on the smallest unique set of columns.

You can then select colors by joining and filtering:

```
SELECT c.ID, c.Color_Name
FROM Color AS c
INNER JOIN ColorMaterialSize AS cms ON c.ID = cms.Color_ID
WHERE cms.Material_ID = 1 AND cms.Size_ID = 2
```

Comment: So from what I've seen with your answer, listing all the combinations in the "ColorMaterialSize" table would be the best practice instead of using a matrix or other solution?

Comment: Yes. Matrices and n-dimensional relations can all be represented using 2-dimensional tables and database engines and languages are designed and optimized for this approach.

Comment: I appreciate your time. So the matrix in your example is The ColorMaterialSize table. So listing every combination that is possible(except for exceptions) is the right idea. So that could lead to a lot of data entry depending the number of combinations.Thanks again.